# Python: Why is it sending duplicate logs to Stackdriver?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am sending logs generated from my data pipeline to Stackdriver on GCP. But for some reason it's sending multiple duplicates of the same event logs. In my `ensure_stackdriver_logging` function, I check to see if the handler already exists to prevent the situation that if `task` is rerun the handler will not be added multiple times. Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
def ensure_stackdriver_logging():
    logger = get_logger()
    lg_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    lg_handler = CloudLoggingHandler(lg_client, 'thinknum_etl_logging')
    if lg_handler not in logger.handlers:
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        lg_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.addHandler(lg_handler)


def task():
    ensure_stackdriver_logging()
    ...
```

Update:

I also tried this --

```
def ensure_stackdriver_logging():
    logger = get_logger()

    if hasattr(logger, 'initialized'):
        return logger
    else:
        setattr(logger, 'initialized', True)

    lg_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    lg_handler = CloudLoggingHandler(lg_client, 'thinknum_etl_logging')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    lg_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(lg_handler)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the `ensure_stackdriver_logging()` method in another place or even added a logger handler before, it will happen twice (or more) because your if check doesn't work as you expect.

When you do the `if lg_handler not in logger.handlers:` check, the comparison that takes place is between the `lg_handler` object ID and the other objects in the list, but because you've just created `lg_handler` in the line before the list, it will not be in the list.

Take this as an example:

```
class Foo():
    pass

l = [Foo()]
b = Foo()
print(b in l)
>>> False
```

`b` is not in the list, because that object that `b` points to is not in the list, but rather a `Foo` object that has the same values.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense. So how do I do a check if the handler exists for a logger that already comes pre-configured with other handlers? In this case I want to do a check for the GCP Stackdriver handler

Comment: @RileyHun You should probably implement the `__eq__` function of your handler, which will check if two instances of the handler are the same by comparing their fields.

When you implement that function, it will also work with your code from the question, as the `in` operator will try and use your `__eq__` implementation.

Comment: I've tried using hasattr and setattr but didn't work either.

Comment: @RileyHun Can you attach the code that you've tried using?